# Objective-C Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

How can I change this line of code `[NgnAVSession releaseSession: &audioSession];` so that I will no longer get this error:

> Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for
>   write-back

this is the whole method

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [NgnAVSession releaseSession: &audioSession];
    [UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = NO;
}
```

Here is the declaration of releaseSession

Header

```
+(void) releaseSession: (NgnAVSession**) session;
```

Implementation

```
+(void) releaseSession: (NgnAVSession**) session{
        @synchronized (kSessions){
            if (session && *session){
                if([(*session) retainCount] == 1){
                    [kSessions removeObjectForKey:[*session getIdAsNumber]];
                }
                else {
                    [(*session) release];
                }
                *session = nil;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have searched some codes that gets the same error as mine but I don't know how to edit my code like they do.

Comment: Okay Sir, I updated it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old library. Try getting a newer version.

Then read up how Cocoa use NSError*. You *really* need to do this, because otherwise you cannot possibly understand what's going on.

Long story short: The compiler assumes that you pass the address of an autoreleasing variable. If needed it can turn a local variable into an autoreleasing one. That cannot be done with a non-local variable.

What these guys are doing is just wrong, wrong, wrong, wrong, wrong. If they want to keep track of all sessions without counting references, the easiest way is to create a wrapper object holding a weak reference, putting the wrapper objects into the array, and in the dealloc method you can remove the object from the array.

I'd suggest that you throw away their releaseSession and do exactly what I said before.

Comment: I wish I could get a newer version but they want me to use this. I'll try to follow what you said but I need to digest it first. I'm not yet good at iOS programming so this might be difficult for me I guess.